# correlation matrix of an AR(1) process

Tags: correlation

Suppose we have a process whose elements follow an AR(1) pattern with correlation $\rho$.  I am confused, concerning the following:
The exact form of the $(i,j)$ element of the correlation matrix P is $\rho^{|i-j|}/(1-\rho^2)$ or $\rho^{|i-j|}$?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how it would be $\rho^{|i-j|}/(1-\rho^2)$ since that would allow correlations above $1$.  In fact, that matrix could have correlations approaching $\infty$ for $\rho$ near $1$.

Comment: The variance-covariance matrix for this case is $V=(\sigma^2 / (1- \rho^2)) * \rho^{i-j}$. This is why i am confused. For example, if i have a fixed value for $\sigma$ and i want to simulate a correlation matrix for an AR(1) process, which form of the matrix i must use?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "simulate a correlation matrix".  But you just pointed out the difference:  The matrix in this comment is the covariance matrix, and the other one is the correlation matrix.

Comment: Maybe you should start another question on how to simulate an auto-regressive process using its covariance matrix.